# jQuery send data to a new open tab and get the data

Tags: php, jquery

I want to send some data from `ClassA` to `ClassB` . So what I did is I create a hidden form in my `ClassA` view page and post it to `ClassB`.

```
<form id="invisible_form" action="classB" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input id="post_to_chatroom" name="hiddenform" type="hidden" value="default">
</form>
```

Then from the js part

```
let recid   = $(this).attr('data-recid');
let chatid  = $(this).attr('data-chatid');
$('#post_to_chatroom').attr({
    'post_recid' : recid,
    'post_chatid': chatid
});
$('#invisible_form').submit();
```

But then I dont know how can I get the post data from `ClassA`. I have tried getting the data from `$_POST` in the php controller but it didnt work.

`ClassB` controller

```
$t1 = isset($_POST['post_recid']) ? $_POST['post_recid'] : 'null';
$t2 = isset($_POST['post_chatid']) ? $_POST['post_chatid'] : 'null';
$jscript = "var postRecid =".$t1.";";
$jscript .= "var postChatid =".$t2.";";
```

but what I get is all `null` value. So how can I get the post data value from class A?

Comment: How about adding submit button  ?

Comment: i have a click function to submit the hidden form already. It just doesnt work to get the data from POST

Comment: You are setting attr not input value attribute . Server code will check if value attribute is set or not that's the reason its giving you null..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With post data you can only send value attribute. You can add another two hidden fields.

```
<input name="post_recid" type="hidden" value="Your value">
<input name="post_chatid" type="hidden" value="Your value">
```

Or you can use [jquery post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to send data without submission.

Comment: then how to get the data from `ClassB` ?

Comment: $_POST['post_recid'] and $_POST['post_chatid'] will work with this